# Xamarin.iOS code signing key error when Archive for Publishing

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, code-signing

Working in Xamarin attempting to Archive for Publishing to obtain the `.ipa` file to upload my build to iTunes Connect, I get the following error:

`iOS code signing key 'iPhone Distribution: [Company Name] (Team Id Number)' not found in keychain.`

I am a member in the company team through in the Developer Account. I have already created the dummy app through Xcode and linked my developer account associated through the team, so the correct provisioning profile is there.

What step(s) am I missing? Why am I not able to release?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No. They ended up just making me Admin in the developer account.

Comment: And the issue still remain? If so, did you try to create a new certificate and provisioning file and signing with that as I also suggested?

Comment: No after I was made admin I was able to do everything I needed to.

Comment: Sounds good. Glad to know you solved your issue. It may be an idea to post your solution as an answer for others to see whom experience the same issue

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your distribution provisioning profile has been downloaded. Simply open XCode and navigate to Preferences -> Account to see the provisioning profiles. The name of the profile varies, as it is set in the Developer Portal.

If your distribution provisioning profile is already installed, then, as mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25768/iphone-code-signing-key-other-developer-name-xxxxx-not-found-in-keychain), try to open your project's options and in the Build/iOS Bundle Signing set "Identity: Developer (Automatic)" and "Provisioning Profile: Automatic". Don't forget that this should be updated for the Release configuration.

Also make sure that your provisioning profiles are still valid in the developer portal. They could have expired. If so, simply click "Renew". Then afterwards, open XCode and navigate to Preferences -> Account and re-download all the provisioning profiles.

Lastly, make sure that you've got the certificate for distribution installed which contain the private key. This is required for publishing.

If everything else fails, you could consider trying to generate a new certificate and provisioning profile in the Developer Portal for distribution.

Comment: Your link was the first thing I tried yesterday morning, same error. The profiles are not expired.

Comment: Are you sure you set the Identity and Provisioning Profile for the Release configuration? Also, are you certain that you have installed the provisioning profile for distribution, and not only the one for development?

Comment: I'm not certain if the distribution profile is installed or not. Since I'm only a member, I'm not able to download it through the developer account. Am I able to do this through XCode ?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to download the distribution provisioning profile in XCode for your Account. If you don't see it, that is why the issue occurs in the first place. If you cannot download it from XCode, you can have someone from your team copy the provisioning profile to you. Simply double-clicking the profile will install it.

Comment: Verified that I have all the profiles downloaded in Xcode so that wasn't it either. I think I'm going to try and reinstall everything, including the provision profiles.

Comment: What about the certificates? When signing for distribution, you need to ensure that you have got the distribution certificate installed in Keychain which also contains the private key. Otherwise, you will see the same error. The reason that this is difficult to solve, is that there are many possibly reasons that the error could have happened

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you generated the provisioning profile for the certificate you're using.
Also make sure that you're selecting the correct certificate and provisioning under iOS project > Options, make sure that you're not running with the Automatic certificate or profile.